# Cocos2d-x Schedule does not call function

Tags: call, cocos2d-x, schedule

It's very simple schedule code. AMS_Moving Inherited CCNode.

I call the `action()` in `runAction()` by schedule. But does not call `action()`.

When I call action() directly, It's normal.

I want know the reason. please help me.

```
void AMS_Moving::runAction()
{
..
..
    this->schedule(schedule_selector(AMS_Moving::action));
}

void AMS_Moving::action(ccTime dt)
{
..
}
```

Comment: Same problem here how to fix bro ?

Answer (score 4):

I've run into a similiar issue in Cocos2dx-3.8, trying to schedule a selector in one `Scene` I was developing.

My malfunctioning code was:

```
void GameScene::onEnter() {
    this->scheduleOnce(CC_SCHEDULE_SELECTOR(GameScene::scheduledSelector), 3.0);
    this->scheduleUpdate();
}

void GameScene::scheduledSelector(float dt) {
    log("Scheduled selector called...");
}

void GameScene::update(float delta) {
    log("update called...");
}
```

Neither `scheduledSelector` nor `update` got called in this situation.

I found the solution to my problem in the Cocos2dx `Node` documentation: A `Node`'s scheduler will not start scheduling updates until the `Node` calls its `resume` method:

```
/**
 * Resumes all scheduled selectors, actions and event listeners.
 * This method is called internally by onEnter.
 */
virtual void resume(void);
```

My bad was that I overrided Node's onEnter method without calling through the superclass implementation, so the scheduler never got a signal to start the updates. Fixing my onEnter method with:

```
void GameScene::onEnter() {
    Node::onEnter();
    this->scheduleOnce(CC_SCHEDULE_SELECTOR(GameScene::scheduledSelector), 3.0);
    this->scheduleUpdate();
}
```

did the job and both selectors began to be called at the right time.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, this was my problem also.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getScheduler()->scheduleSelector(schedule_selector(AMS_Moving::action),this,1.0f,false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the AMS_Moving::runAction() getting called or CCNode::runAction() getting called? try to avoid using the same function name with cocos2d-x and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getScheduler()->scheduleSelector(schedule_selector(Foo::Updater),this,2.0f,false);
```

One of interesting advantage of this  solution is that your scheduler will works independent of scene replacements during game. you just need to `retain` the `Foo`'s object instead of adding it to some `CCLayer` or `CCScene` that may be deleted later.

**Solution 2:**

- Use this signature for your member-function: `void Foo::Updater(float dt)`
- Call this somewhere in `Foo` functions to start scheduler `this->schedule(schedule_selector(Foo::Updater),2.0f);`
- In this case **You must `addChild()` the object of `Foo` class to some `CCLayer` in order to make scheduler really call your `Updater` function.**

--

Presumption:

1. Cocos2dx v2.2.3
2. `Foo` is the class in which you are trying to run some scheduler in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try set breakpoints in function 'AMS_Moving::action()'. This code will obviously call 'action'.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove ccTime dt from this function AMS_Moving::action. it will work